# Problems building reusable component in SwiftUI

Tags: binding, swiftui

I'm trying to use SwiftUI to build a reusable component I previously implemented with @IBDesignable, but it proving to be more difficult than I would have imagined. The problems are a) initializing the text variable and b) clipping the count value. See the code below.

I've tried modifying the value of the text variable both in an initializer and within the body closure, based on changes in the count value, but neither seems to be allowed.

The limiting of the count value and the initialization of the text variable need to happen both from within the view and also when the client of the view modifies the count value. I don't have a clue how to go about making this happen when the count is modified by the client view

```
    @Binding var count: Int
    @State var text : String = ""
    var maxVal = 5
    var minVal = -5

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField($text,
                      onEditingChanged: validateString
            )
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            HStack {
                Button(
                    action: { self.add(1) },
                    label: { Text("Plus")}
                )
                Button(
                    action: { self.add(-1) },
                    label: { Text("Minus")}
                )
            }
        }
    }

    func setVal(_ num: Int) {
        count = min(max(num, minVal), maxVal)
        if text != String(count) { text = String(count) }
    }

    func validateString(_ flag: Bool) {
        if !flag {
            guard let num = Int(text) else { return }
            setVal(num)
        }
    }

    func add(_ increment: Int) {
        setVal(count + increment)
    }

}
```

If I understood all the internal details of binding and of how SwiftUI rebuilds views, I'm sure I could figure this out. But this is one of the downsides of creating and automatic "it just works" frameworks. I'm very excited about SwiftUI and am hoping to surmount this hurdle in understanding.

Answer (score 1):

You left some parts of the code out, specially how you are trying to initialize your view. But this should get you started.

**Also note that onEditingChanged won't be called until you leave the textField (or hide the keyboard), so clipping won't happen until then.**

*Also I noticed you are using an older TextField initializer that has been deprecated already. I updated to its new version.*

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView : View {
    @State private var count = 3

    var body: some View {
        MyView(count: $count)
    }
}

struct MyView: View {
    @Binding var count: Int
    @State private var text : String

    var maxVal = 5
    var minVal = -5

    init(count: Binding<Int>) {
        self._count = count
        self._text = State(initialValue: "\(count.value)")
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("", text: $text, onEditingChanged: validateString)
                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            HStack {
                Button(
                    action: { self.add(1) },
                    label: { Text("Plus")}
                )
                Button(
                    action: { self.add(-1) },
                    label: { Text("Minus")}
                )
            }
        }
    }

    func setVal(_ num: Int) {
        count = min(max(num, minVal), maxVal)
        if text != String(count) { text = String(count) }
    }

    func validateString(_ flag: Bool) {
        if !flag {
            guard let num = Int(text) else { return }
            setVal(num)
        }
    }

    func add(_ increment: Int) {
        setVal(count + increment)
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried to copy and run the modified code you sent. But it won't even build. I get ```Value of type 'MyView' has no member '_count'```, and the same error for self._text. I  was going to ask you where this underbar syntax came from, but it doesn't seem valid. Also, I don't see that there is any facility to limit the count, when it is set by the client ContentView, which is the other thing I asked about. Maybe this isn't the "SwiftUI way" to limit values - it is what I'm familiar with from the "custom UI control" model I'm used to using

Comment: The code compiles fine. But apparently you are using an old version of Xcode. Last update is Beta 4. Several methods got deprecated, new ones were added and some implementations (such as the property wrappers changed). This last change is what makes the underscode instead of the dollar sign necessary.

Comment: I recommend you upgrade to the latest version when posting a question here, this way answers will be relevant for longer. As for your other question for limiting the count, I'm not sure I understand. Maybe you can add some pseudo-code showing what you would like to achieve.

Comment: First of all, I apologize for not knowing about Xcode beta 4. Unfortunately, when I try to create an Xcode project to contain the code above, it crashes repeatedly. I'm creating a simple MacOS SwiftUI project. I think I'll have to come back to this once Xcode and the APIs stabilize a bit. I'll post at that time.

Comment: Meanwhile, I'm curious about the underscore notation in the initializer. What does that mean and is it documented? Finally, the question of limiting (clipping) the value of count when modified by the client is best explained by example, which I can't create right now because XCode4 is crashing. Maybe it is crashing because I also need to update Catalina, but I can't do that right now because I'm overseas with slow internet.

Comment: Yes, the underscore is documented. It is part of the **property wrapper**. Swift Evolution SE-0258 (https://forums.swift.org/t/se-0258-property-wrappers-third-review/26399). In very few words, the underscore gives you access to the backing storage of the State variable. In past versions, syntax was `$$text` instead of `_text`.

Answer (score 0):

So, basically you forgot to add a `init()` for your reusable component. By default, structs are created with their own initializer for the properties that are declared in those structs. But If you want to build a reusable component you need to add a `init()`. It helped me as I was creating a custom library of reusable SwiftUI components and then using it in my project. So, My public struct in my library had to include a `init()`.

Comment: No, I've tried various approaches with custom initializers, but they don't seem to behave as expected either. Can you find one that works correctly with the above example? Should I post another example with a custom initializer that doesn't work? FWIW, I haven't run into this issue other than with a textField, presumably because it needs a binding and therefore the variable has to be a @state variable.